# breeze withParameters no work with parameter: 0 or parameter: null

Tags: breeze

I need to pass parameters to server, for example:

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Animals')
            .withParameters({
                Param1: 'cat',
                Param2: 0,
                Param3: null
            });

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(success)
            .fail(queryFailed);
```

But, the next error appears:

```
Error retreiving data. No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:2222/Services/Zoo/Animals?Param1=cat'.
```

I change parameters: `Param2: 1, Param3: 5` and all work fine.

The question: Why `withParameters` doesn't put parameters (`0` or `null`) in request URI?

If `withParameters` doesn't work with parameters (`0` or `null`) then I need to create in server n convinations of functions to support differents request URI. Is this correct?, because really I need to pass parameters with values `0` or `null` to server.

Please, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Probably a bug, I will try to repro later today.

Comment: We were able to reproduce and are working on fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed as of Breeze 1.3.6, available now.

Comment: Doesn't work with OData provider from Microsoft yet. Breeze doesn't pass the parameters to datajs library.